# Dynamic arrays in VBScript with Split(). Is there a better way?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, dynamic-arrays

A lot of the scripts I write at my job depend on the creation of dynamically-sizable arrays. Arrays in VBScript make this a pretty arduous task, as one has to `Redim` arrays every time one wants to resize them. To work around this, I've started making comma-delimited strings and using `Split(...)` to create 1D arrays out of it. While this works fantastic for me, I've wondered whether VBScript has a more efficient way of handling this. So I ask StackOverflow; are there?

**Disclaimer**: I'm fully aware that VBScript is a pretty substandard scripting language, but Python requires extra software, which is a bit of a hassle for server automation, and PowerShell isn't a core component yet. I'm learning them both, though!

Comment: Have you looked at Jet queries and / or disconnected recordsets? Jet is installed with Windows.

Comment: @Remou: Yes, I have. Much more code for not much more functionality in most cases. I would use those if I needed sorting or 2D arrays (i.e. rows/columns).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I usually go for is to resize the array each time I add new item to it. In that way the end array will never have any unused entries.

```
ReDim aArray(-1)

For i = 1 To 10
    ReDim Preserve aArray(UBound(aArray) + 1)
    aArray(UBound(aArray)) = i
Next

MsgBox Join(aArray, "," & vbNewLine)
```

Other solution proposed by Carlos is to do it using Dictionary object which is probably cleaner solution:

```
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dic.Add "Item1", ""
dic.Add "Item2", ""
dic.Add "Item3", ""

msgbox Join(dic.Keys, "," & vbNewLine)
```

Thanks,
Maciej

Comment: Never knew I could directly ReDim an array - I thought you had to Dim them first. Thanks! Mighty strange these VBScript arrays.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28VS.85%29.aspx) object?

Comment: I was going to suggest that.  It seems to be the answer to a lot of problems.

Comment: I use Dictionaries when I want k/v pairs. The problem I was referring to was for cases when I need 1D arrays.

Comment: You can certainly use it like a 1D array.